# Which is the better way for token authentication. JWT or anyother method

Tags: node.js, jwt, json-web-signature

I was using JWT authentication on my website for login data. It looks like we can decode the JWT Token without a key. Try the below website. It's shocking to me. So is there any better token authentication method is there apart from JWT Token authentication.

http://calebb.net/

You can try with any key. Example from the site https://medium.com/@siddharthac6/json-web-token-jwt-the-right-way-of-implementing-with-node-js-65b8915d550e

Token: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJkYXRhMSI6IkRhdGEgMSIsImRhdGEyIjoiRGF0YSAyIiwiZGF0YTMiOiJEYXRhIDMiLCJkYXRhNCI6IkRhdGEgNCIsImlhdCI6MTUyNTE5MzM3NywiZXhwIjoxNTI1MjM2NTc3LCJhdWQiOiJodHRwOi8vbXlzb2Z0Y29ycC5pbiIsImlzcyI6Ik15c29mdCBjb3JwIiwic3ViIjoic29tZUB1c2VyLmNvbSJ9.ID2fn6t0tcoXeTgkG2AivnG1skctbCAyY8M1ZF38kFvUJozRWSbdVc7FLwot-bwV8k1imV8o0fqdv5sVY0Yzmg

Comment: Ability to decode is the usefulness of having JWT. It provides a stateless approach to share information across the client and the server. You should not store sensitive information in the JWT token. Yet, JWT facilitates integrity through signing, preventing man-in-the-middle attacks.

Answer (score 1):

The token you provided is a JWS i.e. a **signed** token. As any other digitally signed data, the payload can be read.

I think the confusion comes from the article you mentioned where it is written `Encryption algorithm to be used to protect the token` whereas for JWS the algorithm is a signature algorithm.

Hopefully a user commented `It [the token] is encoded in plain base64`.

Other SO users pointed out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235875/should-jwt-web-token-be-encrypted) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301557/if-you-can-decode-jwt-how-are-they-secure) that are very similar.

- Usually tokens are just signed ([JWS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515))
- Tokens can also be encrypted ([JWE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516)) or signed then encrypted ([nested tokens](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#appendix-A.2))

With appropriate means (session storage only, HTTPS channel, Httponly+secured cookies), JWS can be perfectly secured even if the content can be read.